# Look behind regex in one-liner perl

Tags: perl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to make a one-liner script that prints when `github` is **not** behind `golang`.

For example, `java is a language used in github` should match, but `golang is a language used in github` shouldn't match.

I've tried the expression `/(?<!golang).*github/`, but it doesn't work.

```
echo "golang is a language used in github" |
    perl -nle'print /(?<!golang).*github/ ? "match" : "no match"'
```

This prints `match` instead of `no match`.

How can I do that using "negative look-behind" in Perl?

(Using Perl v5.28.1)

Comment: In your example, the pattern matches at position 0. Position 0 isn't immediately preceded by `golang`, and it is the start of a string that matches `.*github`

Comment: Does it need to match `"java is a language used in github, but golang is not"` (where github *precedes* golang)?

Answer (score 3):

Your expression matches all strings with the word "`github`" in them. Let's see why:

```
/(?<!golang).*github/
```

will match as long as Perl can adjust the `.*` to match just enough characters to not run into a situation where it's immediately preceded by `golang`. Regexes being greedy, the `.*` will match as much as it can while still having the rest of the pattern match.

So if your string is

```
golang is a language used in github
```

The regex can match by assigning string to different parts:

- `(?<!golang)` matches at the beginning of the string
- `.*` gets "`golang is a language used in`"
- `github` gets "`github`"

A potentially costly way to accomplish what you wanted is:

```
/^(?:(?!golang).)*github/
```

It works by making sure none of the characters preceding "`github`" begin the sequence "`golang`".

So

```
echo "java is a language used in github" | perl -ne 'print q!Not golang: !, /^(?:(?!golang).)*github/ ? q!true! : q!false!'
```

will print out `Not golang: true` while

```
echo "golang is a language used in github" | perl -ne 'print q!Not golang: !, /^(?:(?!golang).)*github/ ? q!true! : q!false!'
```

will print out `Not golang: false`.

---

Another (less obfuscated) way is to do two consecutive tests:

```
/^(.*)github/  and  $1 !~ /golang/
```

If you're doing tens or hundreds of thousands of lines, maybe test both ways to find which is faster?

Answer (score 0):

improving Bohemian's,

```
/^(?!.*golang.*github).*github/
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a negative look ahead anchored to start:

```
^(?!.*golang).*github
```

Comment: That will incorrectly fail to match `github golang`.